# How do I send variables from multiple js files to one ejs file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have one js file that sends a couple variable to ejs and that works, but when I try to run a second node js process running another js file, it seems like it won't look in the process that I run second.

What do I need to do to get the ejs file to recognize and receive variable from the second js file?

On the webpage, I get  `<var> is not defined`and it traces back to a render from the first js file even though I'm rendering it from the second js file.

I'm sending it using the following code:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('main', {
   variable: value
   }
});
```

edit:

Trying my best to add an example...

first.js:

```
var variable1 = value1;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('main', {
   variable1: value1
   }
});
```

second.js:

```
var variable2 = value2;

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
   res.render('main', {
   variable2: value2
   }
});
```

When I load main.ejs, it says it can't find variable2 in first.js.. why is it looking in first.js for the variable, even though I'm passing it from second.js?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: EJS **can't** recognize variables from "files", it just gets the data passed into it (by the `render()` method in your example).

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, but if you have pages run by separate processes then you need to pass data via http requests. Otherwise they won't be able to pass data.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to node js. I have first.js that calculates some variables and passes it to main.ejs. I also have second.js that runs separately from first.js that does the same thing. If I run first.js, when I load the webpage from main.ejs, it says the variables from second.js are undefined but it traces back to first.js, so for some reason it is looking in first.js for the variables in second.js. It sees the variables from first.js, though.

Answer (score 0):

> I have first.js that calculates some variables and passes it to main.ejs. I also have second.js that runs separately from first.js that does the same thing.

It doesn't run separately… or at all.

HTTP is based on the simple system of:

1. A client (like a web browser) asks for something
2. The server (like your Express.js based program) responds with something

And those somethings are *single* somethings.

So the browser sends a request for `/`, and then Express looks through the registered routes until it finds a match.

> ```
> app.get('/', (req, res) => {
>    res.render('main', {
>    variable1: value1
>    }
> });
> ```

It runs that function and generates a response.

It never gets to the other function registered for the same route: It has already found a route that allowed it to provide a response. If it kept going and sent another response, then it would be a completely different execution of the EJS script, and a completely different response that the browser wouldn't be expecting.

---

- Write **one** route for handling `/`.
- Call `render` **once** and pass it an object with **all** the data you want
- Split the code up into functions if you want to make it easier to manage. One of the functions can be the route handler itself, and it can call the others and get the data they return. If things get really complex, you can move the functions into separate [modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) and `require` them.

Comment: Thank you very much, Quentin. This helped!

Answer (score 0):

You should implement worker threads https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html to make two node process communicate to each other

```
// first.js
const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')

function runProcess (workerData) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const worker = new Worker('./second.js', { workerData })
    worker.on('message', resolve)
    worker.on('error', reject)
    worker.on('exit', (code) => {
      if (code !== 0) { 
        reject(new Error(`Worker stopped with exit code ${code}`)) 
      }
    })
  })
}

async function run () {
  const result = await runProcess('variable value to send')
  console.log(result)
}

run()
```

---

```
// second.js
const { workerData, parentPort } = require('worker_threads')

parentPort.postMessage({ received: workerData })
```